# SQOOP connection param file error

Tags: sqoop

I want to perform sqoop import from rdbms to hdfs. While importing the data, I have a Date format of type `yyyy--mm--dd hh:mm:ss`. But in hdfs I want the foment to be `yyyy--mm--dd`. So I have use a property

```
-D oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false
```

in connection param file and Sqoop statement is,

```
Sqoop import --connection-param-file filename ....
```

The result is not in the desired format. I want to the property to be in param file. How can I do that?

Comment: please, provide any effort from your side, what code did you wrote?, and in order to users know and better understand your problem, please, post your results..

Comment: the command I used is,      
sqoop import --connection-param-file con --connect jdbc:mysql://mysqlhost --username user --password pass --table table1 -m 1